# Big Cartel theme not taking into account media queries on mobile devices

Tags: ios, mobile, media-queries, bigcartel

I have created a big cartel theme and successfully installed it. Media queries inside the code work correctly on my computer, however when I load the site on my iPhone, it appears at the original width – it should be taking into account the max-device-width: 480px. Any help solving this issue would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the URL of your Big Cartel shop so I can take a look at the code?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you include !important as this overrides all other code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
.class {
  font-size:1.2em !important;
  color:#ffffff;
 }
}
```

Like that.